# SQL server: The statement has been terminated

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

i've been working for this error for about two hours, i feel there's no mistake in my query, but I keep get this error. The worst thing is it doesn't give any further information about what causing the error. I'm using ASP classic and SQL server. can you help me guys? here's my query:

```
    query = "INSERT INTO [127.0.0.1].[tv].[dbo].[BH_REG]([REG_ID],[NAME],[PHONE],[EMAIL],[INST_ADDRESS],[ZIPCODE],[BIRTH_PLACE],[BIRTH],[SEX],[CABLE_DISTANT],[SID],[BID],[STREET_NUMBER],[PID], [REG_DATE], [REG_STATUS], [ORDER_STATUS], [ID_TYPE], [ID_NUMBER], [PROMO_CODE], [VIRTUAL_NUMBER], [BCA_ID], [SALES_CODE], [MAIN_PACKAGE], [MOBILE_PHONE], [PAY_METHOD], [COORDINATE], [TAP_ID], [TAP_PORT_ID],[EXPECTED_SCHEDULE]) "

query = query & "VALUES('"& idxx &"','"& name &"','"& mobilephone &"','"& email &"','"& instaddress &"','"& zipcode &"','"& birthplace &"','"& birth &"','"& sex &"','"& jarakKabel &"','"& sid &"','"& bId &"','"& streetNumber &"','"& aId &"', NULL,'COVERED','REGISTERED','"& idtype &"','"& idnumber &"','"& promoidtext &"','" & virtualcode &"', NULL,'"& salescode &"','"& PackageGroup &"','"& mobilephone &"','"& paymethod &"', '"& installationCoordinate &"', NULL, NULL, '"& expected_schedule &"')"
            Conndev.execute(query)
```

The error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated
>
> /registration/register.asp, line 256

I also get the same error when i tried to insert getdate() on [REG_DATE] field

After getting some clue from you guys, I tried to parameterize my query. Unfortunately another error occurred:

```
ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'
Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.
```

And here's updated code:

```
            <!--#include virtual="ADOVBS.INC"-->

            Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            conn.Open 'my connection string goes here
            set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

            query = "INSERT INTO BH_REG (REG_ID,NAME,PHONE,EMAIL,INST_ADDRESS,ZIPCODE,BIRTH_PLACE,BIRTH,SEX,CABLE_DISTANT,SID,BID,FLOOR,STREET_NUMBER,PID,REG_DATE,REG_STATUS, ORDER_STATUS,ID_TYPE, ID_NUMBER, PROMO_CODE, VIRTUAL_NUMBER, BCA_ID, SALES_CODE, MAIN_PACKAGE, MOBILE_PHONE, PAY_METHOD, COORDINATE, TAP_ID, TAP_PORT_ID,EXPECTED_SCHEDULE) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"


            cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = qText
            cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 900
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@REG_ID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, idxx)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@NAME", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, name)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@PHONE", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, mobilephone)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@EMAIL", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, email)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@INST_ADDRESS", adVarChar, adParamInput, 500, instaddress)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ZIPCODE", adVarChar, adParamInput, 5, zipcode)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@BIRTH_PLACE", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, birthplace)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@BIRTH", adDate, adParamInput, , birth)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@SEX", adVarChar, adParamInput, 6, sex)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@CABLE_DISTANT", adVarChar, adParamInput, 15, jarakKabel)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@SID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, sid)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@BID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, bId)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@FLOOR", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, NULL)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@STREET_NUMBER", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, street_number)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@PID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, aId)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@REG_DATE", adDate, adParamInput, , getdate())
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@REG_STATUS", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "COVERED")
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ORDER_STATUS", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "REGISTERED")
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ID_TYPE", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, idtype)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ID_NUMBER", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, idnumber)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@PROMO_CODE", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, promoidtext)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@VIRTUAL_NUMBER", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, virtualcode)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@BCA_ID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, NULL)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@SALES_CODE", adVarChar, adParamInput, 75, salescode)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@MAIN_PACKAGE", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, PackageGroup)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@MOBILE_PHONE", adVarChar, adParamInput, 35, mobilephone)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@PAY_METHOD", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, paymethod)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@COORDINATE", adVarChar, adParamInput,, installationCoordinate)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@TAP_ID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, NULL)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@TAP_PORT_ID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, NULL)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@EXPECTED_SCHEDULE", adDate, adParamInput, , expected_schedule)

            set rs = cmd.Execute
            set rs = Nothing
            set conn = Nothing
```

Here is the printed out query before I parameterized it:

```
INSERT INTO [127.0.0.1].[tv].[dbo].[BH_REG](
 [REG_ID],[NAME],[PHONE],[EMAIL],[INST_ADDRESS]
,[ZIPCODE],[BIRTH_PLACE],[BIRTH],[SEX]
,[CABLE_DISTANT],[SID],[BID], [FLOOR]
, [STREET_NUMBER],[PID], [REG_DATE]
, [REG_STATUS], [ORDER_STATUS], [ID_TYPE]
, [ID_NUMBER], [PROMO_CODE], [VIRTUAL_NUMBER]
, [BCA_ID], [SALES_CODE], [MAIN_PACKAGE]
, [MOBILE_PHONE],[PAY_METHOD], [COORDINATE]
, [TAP_ID], [TAP_PORT_ID],[EXPECTED_SCHEDULE]
)VALUES(
'H-10210-00276','ALFIN TEST','0888899998888',
'me@gmail.com','BENDUNGAN HILIR 3 NO : 22'
,'10210','','07/15/1981','M','Less than 50'
,'22794','','22','',getdate(),'COVERED'
,'REGISTERED','KTP','123235243212',''
,'8993774013523344', NULL,'','packet 1'
,'0888899998888','Kartu Kredit'
, '-6.2100422217393625,106.81154161691666'
, NULL, NULL, '08/15/2015'
)
```

Comment: Print out the query after variable substitution and include that in your question.

Comment: This will be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Use query parameters instead, to avoid this **massive** security problem, and that will likely fix the error in your question as well.

Comment: Check the lengths of your column's. The data you are inserting should be less or equal to the columnn length

Comment: is it SQL SERVER syntax

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn yes I know, but honestly, I'm new to this ASP classic language also this "spaghetti" code is inherited to me from former programmer. I don't really care about the security for now but deadline. :(
I'll try to use query parameter as you suggested. let see if it works.

Comment: I'm sure query parameters will fix your question problem, too, because it looks like you're trying to enclose some integer columns in quotes, and that's likely a big part of the problem. Query parameters avoids the need to use quotes for any of those values.

Comment: @tinka all I know it's an sql syntax for windows machine. im not familiar with sql server. I used to be MySql user.

Comment: Being presented with such a major security issue and stating you don't care as long as you meet your deadline is a very poor attitude to have about development. I can tell you from experience if you don't do it right in the beginning you won't go back and fix it until something bad happens. Take pride in your work and do it correctly.

Comment: @Sean Lange Like i said it just "for now". To be honest, I always been really careful programmer especially when dealing with security. But since tomorrow morning I have to present this product to very non-technical audience, well, my employer actually, they don't really care about the code behind. Plus, this is under development stage right now, and not in production. Anyway, thanks for your advice. I will keep it in my mind. :)

Comment: Well as suggested previously, parametering your queries will prevent sql injection AND fix the issue you are facing right now. It is the best of both worlds. :D

Comment: I'm writing it right now. I will post the code as an answer when it succeed. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Apparently, I cannot get it to work. Error: "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another". I have included ADOVBS.INC. failed. set the adCmdText constant manually. failed. It's been an hour. And i still have 8 tasks to do. I hope you can give me some clue. Thanks

Comment: if you cannot print out the value of `query`, then obviously one of the many variables you have is the issue. For that, you need to figure it out.  Of course, if you parameterized it, it might be easier.

Comment: I added the printed value of the query to my question. please check it out.

Comment: For starters you shouldn't be using `adovbs.inc` it will just bite you in the bum later on, but you seem more interested in hitting a deadline then coding it right and I can't work with that. There are too many of those in the industry as it is.

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks for your advice. As I said before, I inherited legacy code from former employee. And I barely use ASP classic for 2 days. I can't help it. But I tried my best to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anybody who recommends parameterized queries as *easier* to debug is smoking something. :)

This is likely to be caused by one or more of your values not matching the data type of the corresponding field, but trying to figure out which one is the problem in a long list of parameters will leave you bald. Instead, open a recordset (with zero rows), do an .Addnew, and set each field one-by-one in your code.

```
Set rs = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
query = "SELECT TOP 0 * FROM BH_REG"
rs.Open query, conn, 1, 2
rs.AddNew
    rs("REG_ID") = idxx
    rs("NAME") = name
    '...
    rs("EXPECTED_SCHEDULE") = expected_schedule
rs.Update
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

This way, ASP will tell you exactly which line is causing the trouble, you can figure out why it's the wrong datatype, fix it/prevent it, and *then* you can convert it all to a stored procedure or whatever.

Comment: hehe in a modern programming language it is easier...but classic asp is just awful for debugging. This seems like a pretty neat way to make that part of the process a little less painful.

Comment: What a load of rot! Parameterised queries are simpler to debug I do it all the time and it beats using the bloated `ADODB.Recordset` for simple CRUD operations, please do not advocate this approach.

Comment: @Lankymart why? what's wrong with this approach? can you explain? for me this code look clearer. Do we have to 'always do it the right way?' . If one approach give the expected result without any drawback, I prefer to call it 'creativity' instead of call it 'the wrong way'.

Comment: @Martha your solution works like a charm. Thanks so much.

Comment: @SeanLange thank you so much for your help and patient. Those advice really helps me to understand the problem :)

Comment: @Lankymart: I'm not advocating this approach for production code, but you really can't beat it for debugging.

Comment: @under5hell You're not understanding anything, thats why any solution however poor will work for you well thats your progative I guess.

Comment: @Martha You're not? Oh well that's ok then...but wait if you providing these approaches to those who don't know any better, where do you think they'll end up?

Comment: @Lankymart: hammers can be used to bash in someone's head. Does that mean that hammers shouldn't ever be used to drive in a nail, and we shouldn't tell new construction workers about the existence of hammers?

Comment: Nice illustration but doesn't fit the context. Who's to say you're not advocating bashing someone's head in with a hammer? Its far too abstract and can be applied to / twisted to anything.

Comment: @Lankymart For now let's assume that I know NOTHING. you don't answer my question yet. What's wrong with this approach? if you're willing to explain, it might be very valuable for me and for those you called 'who don't know any better'.

Comment: @under5hell: from what I understand, the major objection to this approach is speed. All else being equal, adding a row via `rs.AddNew` will be noticeably slower than `INSERT INTO`. However, the actual arguments tend to get lost in "OMG!!1! That's, like, so old-fashioned! It must be absolutely horrible and subject to SQL Injection and syphilis and Lyme disease as well!!!" (It's *not* actually subject to SQL Injection.)

Comment: It doesn't need yet another thread on this subject the internet is teaming with them. Google is your friend, if you are truly interested lookup "ado recordset addnew versus sql insert".

Comment: @Lankymart: on my computer, that search returns a bunch of instructions about how to use .addnew, and one 10-year-old thread on vbforums that has someone explaining that .addnew could leave a transaction open indefinitely "while the user gets a cup of coffee", which is such utter nonsense that I don't know whether to laugh or cry. So, we're back to "OMG!!!1!" land.

Comment: @Martha Try searching it in the context of asp.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shot in the dark. You were using a number of parameters for NULLs. Those are pointless and just add confusion. Also there is no point in parameterizing hard coded values so remove also. Here is what your query should look like.

```
INSERT INTO BH_REG 
(
    REG_ID
    , NAME
    , PHONE
    , EMAIL
    , INST_ADDRESS
    , ZIPCODE
    , BIRTH_PLACE
    , BIRTH
    , SEX
    , CABLE_DISTANT
    , SID
    , BID
    , STREET_NUMBER
    , PID
    , REG_DATE

    , ID_TYPE
    , ID_NUMBER
    , PROMO_CODE
    , VIRTUAL_NUMBER
    , SALES_CODE
    , MAIN_PACKAGE
    , MOBILE_PHONE
    , PAY_METHOD
    , COORDINATE
    ,EXPECTED_SCHEDULE
) VALUES
(
    ? 'regid
    , ? 'name
    , ? 'phone
    , ? 'email
    , ? 'inst_address
    , ? 'zip
    , ? 'birthplace
    , ? 'birth
    , ? 'sex
    , ? 'cable_distant
    , ? 'sid
    , ? 'bid
    , ? 'street_number
    , ? 'pid
    , ? 'reg_date
    , "COVERED"
    , "REGISTERED"
    , ? 'id_type
    , ? 'id_number
    , ? 'promo_code
    , ? 'virtual_number
    , ? 'sales_code
    , ? 'main_package
    , ? 'mobile_phone
    , ? 'pay_method
    , ? 'coordinate
    , ? 'expected_schedule
)
```

If the types are wrong or you get conflicts it is because of how you set those parameters. I can't help you much there because it would be in the variables and getting them converted to the correct datatypes.

Comment: Thank you. This answer is really helpful for me :)